# How to fix `TypeError: get_sheet_by_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name' error` in `openpyxl`

Tags: openpyxl

I am trying to display my worksheet names using `openpyxl`. I get the error "TypeError: get_sheet_by_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'" How can I fix this?

I am on windows 10 OS. I am using Python 3.7 with `openpyxl` installed pip.

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\zhiva\Desktop')
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
wb.get_sheet_by_name()
wb.get_sheet_by_name()
```

I expected the output as ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3']

Comment: Assuming that you are loading the wb properly, use `wb.sheetnames`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you want is:

```
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

`wb.get_sheet_by_name` will get a specific sheet, but you have to pass it the name, hence the error.

See [documentation](https://module-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/openpyxl.html#getting-sheets-from-the-workbook)

Answer (score 0):

Can use this as well,

```
wb_obj.sheetnames
```

Output :

```
['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
```

And in case, if specific worksheet is required, then

```
wb_obj['Sheet12']
```